# Difference between Qt mac open source and qt mac cocoa libraries

Tags: cocoa, qt, open-source, libraries

What is the difference between qt mac open source and qt mac cocoa libraries?

I found on http://releases.qt-project.org/qt4/source/ these dmg files and i don't know what's the difference between them:

`qt-mac-cocoa-opensource-4.6.4-debug-libs.dmg` and `qt-mac-opensource-4.6.4-debug-libs.dmg`

`qt-mac-cocoa-opensource-4.6.4.dmg` and `qt-mac-opensource-4.6.4.dmg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I found out the difference between the two is that `qt-mac-cocoa-opensource-4.6.4.dmg` versions are built using cocoa API and `qt-mac-opensource-4.6.4-debug-libs.dmg` are built using carbon API which now is obsolete.